# Simulate php array language construct or parse with regexp?

Tags: php, regex, parsing

From an external source I'm getting strings like

```
array(1,2,3)
```

but also a larger arrays like

```
array("a", "b", "c", array("1", "2", array("A", "B")), array("3", "4"), "d")
```

I need them to be an actual array in php. I know I could use eval but since it are untrusted sources I'd rather not do that. I also have no control of the external sources.

Should I use some regular expressions for this (if so, what) or is there some other way?

Comment: Your external source is giving you a string like this "array(1,2,3)" and you want to turn that text into a php array?

Comment: This is going to be though... That's not a serialization format PHP recognizes.

Comment: Can you control the external source? Is it possible to ask them to generate JSON or XML instead?

Comment: @jonathan: Yes I want that to be put in a PHP array (just like you would get with eval() but for security reasons don't want to use eval.
@KennyTM: I don't have any control over the external source, so I have to work with this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whilst writing a parser using the Tokenizer which turned out not as easy as I expected, I came up with another idea: Why not parse the array using `eval`, but first validate that it contains nothing harmful?

So, what the code does: It checks the tokens of the array against some allowed tokens and chars and then executes eval. I do hope I included all possible harmless tokens, if not, simply add them. (I intentionally didn't include HEREDOC and NOWDOC, because I think they are unlikely to be used.)

```
function parseArray($code) {
    $allowedTokens = array(
        T_ARRAY                    => true,
        T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING => true,
        T_LNUMBER                  => true,
        T_DNUMBER                  => true,
        T_DOUBLE_ARROW             => true,
        T_WHITESPACE               => true,
    );
    $allowedChars = array(
        '('                        => true,
        ')'                        => true,
        ','                        => true,
    );

    $tokens = token_get_all('<?php '.$code);
    array_shift($tokens); // remove opening php tag

    foreach ($tokens as $token) {
        // char token
        if (is_string($token)) {
            if (!isset($allowedChars[$token])) {
                throw new Exception('Disallowed token \''.$token.'\' encountered.');
            }
            continue;
        }

        // array token

        // true, false and null are okay, too
        if ($token[0] == T_STRING && ($token[1] == 'true' || $token[1] == 'false' || $token[1] == 'null')) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!isset($allowedTokens[$token[0]])) {
            throw new Exception('Disallowed token \''.token_name($token[0]).'\' encountered.');
        }
    }

    // fetch error messages
    ob_start();
    if (false === eval('$returnArray = '.$code.';')) {
        throw new Exception('Array couldn\'t be eval()\'d: '.ob_get_clean());
    }
    else {
        ob_end_clean();
        return $returnArray;
    }
}

var_dump(parseArray('array("a", "b", "c", array("1", "2", array("A", "B")), array("3", "4"), "d")'));
```

I think this is a good comprimise between security and convenience - no need to parse yourself.

For example

```
parseArray('exec("haha -i -thought -i -was -smart")');
```

would throw exception:

```
Disallowed token 'T_STRING' encountered.
```

Comment: I was having the same thought :) I haven't given up on the idea of making it entirly with the tokeniser though, but I'll explore your script first., thanks

Answer (score 6):

You could do:

```
json_decode(str_replace(array('array(', ')'), array('[', ']'), $string)));
```

Replace the array with square brackets. Then `json_decode`. If the string is just a multidimensional array with scalar values in it, then doing the `str_replace` will not break anything and you can `json_decode` it. If it contains any code, it will also replace the function brackets and then the Json won't be valid and `NULL` is returned.

Granted, that's a rather, umm, creative approach, but might work for you.

**Edit:** Also, see the comments for some further limitiations pointed out by other users.

Comment: I can't test this right now, but that is an elegant solution if it returns properly. +1

Comment: @KennyTM yeah that wouldnt work. I'll leave it up there nonetheless, so the OP can decide if it's of any use

Comment: And this is for arrays only. Won't work on associative arrays.

Comment: It's creative, but I like it and it might just do the trick. It will be pretty simple arrays anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the [Tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) for this. Maybe I will write a script lateron, that actually does it.