# Sandboxing Users' PHP Code

Tags: php, security, sandbox

I want to limit what PHP functionality my users have access to.

For instance there is an object `$data` and the user likes to use `if` `for` and `echo`.

Obviously allowing him to write PHP would be a serious vulnerability.

Is there any way to run this PHP in a sandbox or would you recommend any lightweight PHP template engine?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324726/is-there-a-way-to-execute-php-code-in-a-sandbox-from-within-php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't have your own server you probably don't have runkit. But what you do have (probably) is [Tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/de/book.tokenizer.php)! Using the Tokenizer you may look through the given source code and abort if you find an invalid token. [Here an example how to validate an array using this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267951/simulate-php-array-language-construct-or-parse-with-regexp/3268443#3268443). You could do same for your purpose. The PHP documentation has [a list of tokens](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php). If you need help deciding which tokens to allow or to disallow, please say so.

€dit: And obviously I do recommend to use [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/), too. It is so nice - and has sandboxing!

Comment: Twig has sandboxed template code. This is not as good as runkit-sandbox but I don't have to reinstall the php server. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

The only one I know so far is [runkit](http://www.php.net/runkit).

> The runkit extension provides means to
>   modify constants, user-defined
>   functions, and user-defined classes.
>   It also provides for custom
>   superglobal variables and embeddable
>   sub-interpreters via sandboxing.

**Update:**

I could find these two links regarding zend and runkit you should take a look at:

http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Http_Server+-+Mat+Scales
http://www.dunfy.me.uk/?p=38

Comment: Runkit requires Thread Safety to be enabled and Zend requires Thread Safety to be disabled.. Is there a way to use Zend and Runkit?

Comment: `The Runkit_Sandbox class is only available as of PHP 5.1.0 or specially patched versions of PHP 5.0, and requires that thread safety be enabled`
In my `phpinfo()` runkit is enabled however runkit_sandbox is  disabled probably because of the the thread safety

Comment: @Ghommey: That's what we have so far :(

Answer (score 4):

Along the lines of smarty, give [twig](http://www.twig-project.org/) a try!

There is also a very robust [extension system](http://www.twig-project.org/book/04-Extending-Twig) which allows you to allow/disallow built-in or custom tags, token parsers, nodes, etc in the template language itself.  This way, users can have basic logic (conditional statements, "functions" (blocks) and iterators) without resorting to the evils of eval.

Comment: Twig blows smarty out of the water and it's still in active development.

Answer (score 2):

Tried Smarty?  http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: @Ghommey: If you really only want customizeable output, then this is your choice. A template engine is a lot easier to maintain than a php-sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

The PECL [runkit extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) does provide sandboxing, but it's possibly a bit overkill for what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Fat-Free Framework](http://fatfree.sourceforge.net) has a template engine that prohibits the use of PHP code and allows you to define which functions can be used inside HTML templates.

There's also a real sandboxing feature that makes functions and include files independent of others, i.e. variables/functions in one include file are not known to others, so you can have a function with an identical name as another include file. This may be of some use for (dysfunctional) developer teams.