# Check if a string is valid PHP code

Tags: php, syntax-checking

I want to do:

```
$str = "<? echo 'abcd'; ?>";
if (is_valid_php($str)){
   echo "{$str} is valid";
} else {
   echo "{$str} is not valid PHP code";
}
```

Is there a simple way to do the `is_valid_php` check?

All I can find is online php syntax checkers and command-line ways to check syntax, or [`php_check_syntax`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-check-syntax.php) which only works for a file, and I don't want to have to write to a file to check if the string is valid.

I'd rather not use `system()`/`exec()` or `eval()`

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861932/alternative-to-systemphp-l) - It's old, so I'm hoping there's something new

[Other Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378959/is-there-a-static-code-analyzer-like-lint-for-php-files) - all the options (as far as I could tell) either are no longer supported or use command line or have to check files (not strings)

I don't need a full-fledged compiler or anything. I literally only need to know if the string is valid PHP code.

**EDIT:** By **valid php code**, I mean that it can be executed, has no compiler/syntax errors, and should contain only PHP code. It could have runtime errors and still be valid, like `$y = 33/0;`. And it should contain only PHP... Such as, `<div>stuff</div><? echo "str"; ?>` would be invalid, but `<? echo "str"; ?>` and `echo "$str";` would be valid

Comment: What about posting curl requests to those online syntax checkers? I don't know the sites, so I'm not sure if its possible, but you could observer the network requests and see if you can emulate it with cURL

Comment: Can you clarify "valid"? Does that mean free of both compile time and run time errors? Or works as expected?

Comment: All I can find is the same as you did. I checked a REST service, but that one also takes a file. Writing (and deleting) a file is quite a trivial task - so I  am curious, why don't you want to write to a file to use php_check_syntax?

Comment: Best I could find: https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser

Comment: Maybe you can use [`phc`](http://www.phpcompiler.org/) to compile the code into an executable? I have never used this software but I would imagine that if the script is not valid PHP code then the build should fail.

Comment: @dan08, That could work, but for performance reasons, I do not want to send curl requests, since I'm going to be checking 10+ separate strings in a single request (granted, that's only while my site is in development mode, so I guess it's not a big deal).

Comment: @TobiasBeuving, performance reasons and laziness. But obviously, I could wrap it in a function and write to a temporary file and make it easy to use. It's probably the route that I will go, but just checking the string would be preferred, if that were an option.

Comment: @HPierce, I updated my question to explain... The php-parser or phc seem like good options.

Comment: @Jakar I understand that checking string would be way nicer, and writing to and deleting a file and stuff is just a silly redundant job. Depending on how many times you want to check that code, writing to a file does not easily affect performance. If I were you I start doing the write to file thing right away before trying anything else, but thats me :)

Answer (score 7):

You could pipe the string to php -l and call it using shell_exec:

```
$str1 = "<?php echo 'hello world';";
$str2 = "<?php echo 'hello world'";
echo isValidPHP($str1) ? "Valid" : "Invalid"; //Valid
echo isValidPHP($str2) ? "Valid" : "Invalid"; //Inalid

function isValidPHP($str) {
    return trim(shell_exec("echo " . escapeshellarg($str) . " | php -l")) == "No syntax errors detected in -";
}
```

Just had another idea... this time using `eval` but safely:

test_code.php

```
$code = "return; " . $_GET['code'];
//eval is safe here because it won't do anything
//since the first thing we do is return
//but we still get parse errors if it's not valid
//If that happens, it will crash the whole script, 
//so we need it to be in a separate request
eval($code); 
return "1";
```

elsewhere in your code:

```
echo isValidPHP("<?php echo \"It works!\";");

function isValidPHP($code) {
    $valid = file_get_contents("http://www.yoursite.com/test_code.php?" . http_build_query(['code' => $code]));
    return !!$valid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, this is easiest.

```
$str = "<? echo 'abcd'; ?>";
file_put_contents("/some/temp/path", $str);
exec("php -l /some/temp/path", $output, $result);
if ($result == 0){
   echo "{$str} is valid";
} else {
   echo "{$str} is not valid PHP code";
}
unlink("/some/temp/path");
```

The reason I didn't use `php_check_syntax` is because:

1. it's deprecated
2. it actually executes the code

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Just saw that you want to rather refrain from using exec().
I think this is going to be very hard without it though, php removed the check_syntax function for a reason.
Maybe ( and I really am just guessing here when it comes to the effort you want to invest ) running the php -l in a container ( docker pretty much these days ) and passing the code via a http call to the docker daemon ( just a run command against the standard php cli would do it here ). Then you could use something like below code example without worries ( provided you don't give any permissions to your container obv ).

You could use exec and the php commandline like this:

```
$ret = exec( 'echo "<?php echo \"bla\";" | php -l 2> /dev/null' );

echo strpos( $ret, 'Errors parsing' ) !== false ? "\nerror" : "\nno error";

$ret = exec( 'echo "<?php eccho \"bla\";" | php -l 2> /dev/null' );

echo strpos( $ret, 'Errors parsing' ) !== false ? "\nerror" : "\nno error";
```

which returns:

```
no error
error
```

No file needed thanks to piping the output. Also using the redirection to dev null we get no unwanted output elsewhere.
Still surely a little dirty, but the shortest I can come up with.