# Replace [diggin] with HTML code or PHP code

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have this string

```
$s = 'Yo be [diggin = array("fruit"=> "apple")] scriptzors!';
```

which then gets checked by

```
$matches = null;
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $s, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

but what I want it to do is the following, it should return the following

```
print "yo be";
$this->diggin(SEND ARRAY HERE);
print "scriptzors!";
```

EDIT to show issue with below answer

```
$s = 'Yo be [diggin = array("fruit"=>"apple")] scriptzors!';
$matches = null; 
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $s, $matches);

$var = explode(' = ', $matches[1]);
print $var[0]; //THIS DOES NOT PRINT
```

Comment: The return part is strange to me. What should your $s string be converted to ?

Comment: its just text, from our database, and i want to allow our staff to pur plugins or run functions inside the content which is a website.

think like wordpress

Comment: What does this "$this->diggin(SEND ARRAY HERE);" do? What does your output looks like when converted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sort of close. You can [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string with `=` but with spaces included around the `=`. Then the first element would be the function name, in this case `diggin` and the second element would be the array but as a string. You'll need to [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) that one so that it'll be a proper array data type.

```
$var = explode(' = ', $matches[1][0]);
call_user_func_array(array($this, $var[0]), eval($var[1] . ';'));
// or do 
$this->{var[0]}(eval($val[1] . ';'));
```

As an alternative, you can also modify the regex so that you don't have to call `explode`.

```
preg_match_all('/\[([a-z0-9_]*)\s*?=\s*(.*)\]/i', $s, $matches);
```

Either way, you'll want to make sure that you sanitize the user input because `eval` can be [**ev**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499672/when-if-ever-is-eval-not-evil)[**il**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php).

Comment: Can I ask how do I make it put it in the correct part? that does the turn {} into function but what about the splitting of the content in the $s so the function is inserted where the {} is

Comment: You should split the content of `$s` for every "function call" you found in the string. When you've got everything (i.e. all functions are called), constitute back the strings that you split before.

Comment: for some reason its not getting the $var[0]

Comment: I have edited my answer to show issue with answer. Maybe I am doing it wrong

Comment: Ah, my bad. The right one is `$var = explode(' = ', $matches[1][0]);`

Comment: its still not turning the $var[1] into an array

Comment: That's what the `eval` is for. If you want to have `$var[1]` as an array. Simply call `eval` while assign `$var[1]` to the array string. `eval('$var[1] = '.$var[1].';');`

Answer (score 0):

This will call the function without using eval and exposing yourself to code injection.

```
preg_match_all('/\[([a-z0-9_]*)\s*?=\s*array\((.*)*\)\]/i', $s, $matches);
$var = explode(',', $matches[2][0]);
$result = array();
foreach ($var as $value) {
    $keyvaluepair = explode('=>', $value);
    $result[$keyvaluepair[0]] = $keyvaluepair[1];
}
$this->{var[0]}($result);
```