# In PHP, can I store division or multiplication along with a number?

Tags: php

In PHP, I can do this:

```
$value1 = 5;
$value2 = -2;
echo $value1 + $value2; // 3
```

But how would I do this with multiplication or division? Something like:

```
$value1 = 10;
$value2 = /2;
echo $value1 (?) $value2; // 5;
```

How would I manage this situation as simply as possible?

Comment: are you asking if you can add the operator to a string and evaluate as math? as you put it here, /2 is invalid. It will throw an error

Comment: I know it will. I'm asking how to do this properly, without an error.

Comment: fair enough, is the question then how to add the opoerator as a string within the value of a variable or are you just looking for a yes or no it can't be done this way. Cause I think succinctly the answer is no. Though the bigger question may be why do you want to do it this way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need to differentiate between division and multiplication,

```
$value2 = 2;
//or
$value2 = 1/2;

echo $value1 * $value2;
```

Your code works with addition and subtraction, because `-2` in `$value2 = -2;` does not mean "subtract two". It means "[add] minus two". For multiplication, you need "two" or "the inverse of two"

Comment: This seems like the most reasonable solution, thanks! Vdaka! :)

Comment: it should be noted that $value2 = 1/2 is actually doing the math. it is dividing 1 by 2. You could replace 1/2 with .5 to avoid the minuscule unnecessary processing. Just saying. This is a good solution as is in general use

Comment: I don't think saying .5 is the proper solution. The answer works generally for any number I'd want to input, for example 1/400, or whatever. It should stay as it is.

Comment: @KaiQing There is no exact decimal representation of 1/3. A compiler should optimise '1/2` anyways. There ARE true compilers for PHP.

Comment: yeah but you can come close depending on your needs. Like I said, the answer as is works as needed. All I am pointing out is that it is not like saying $value2 = half. It is saying $value2 = divide one by two.

Answer (score 3):

In a word, no.

In a paragraph, you could create an anonymous function to capture the meaning of your `$value2`:

```
$value1 = 5;
$op_and_value2 = function($value) {
  return $value1 / 2;
};

echo $op_and_value2($value1); # 2
```

Or you could make a class to encapsulate this behaviour, but that's even more work.

Or you can go to the dark side, and use `eval`.

```
$value1 = 5;
$value2 = "/ 2";
echo eval("return $value1 $value2;"); # 2
```

(If "dark side" wasn't hint enough, don't do this unless you want everyone to hate you.)

A better approach all around would be to store operator and value2 separately (although, you can still put them into a structure together); the operator would be best stored as a function (perhaps an anonymous function like above, but with two arguments, and not a hard-coded `2`).

Comment: This sort of makes me feel good that I am not the only one who suggested `eval`...

Comment: @aam1r: Haha... well, as a literal answer to the question, it just pops into one's mind. But I do feel dirty just for mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it is an unpleasant way of doing this:

You can use `eval()`:

```
$value1 = 10;
$value2 = "/2";
echo eval("return $value1 $value2;"); // 5;
```

I would be very cautious in using `eval()` in code running in production though. If you end up using this approach, I would suggest reading these 2 discussions:

- [When is eval evil in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php)
- [When (if ever) is eval NOT evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499672/when-if-ever-is-eval-not-evil)