# If Eval Is Considered Evil, Then

Tags: php, eval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [when is eval evil in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php)
>   [When (if ever) is eval NOT evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499672/when-if-ever-is-eval-not-evil)

Just as my question states, [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) runs the contents as PHP Scripting directly.

in what cause would this be used; people refer to `eval();` as an evil function to even consider using.

Why is it still in PHP when it is a very unusable/insecure function?

Comment: It isn't unusable, you just have to think long and hard before you use it.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php?rq=1

Comment: @OliCharlesworth No, this question is asking/trying to spark up a debate on why eval is still in PHP, not asking  for the usage of it

Comment: @user1968541: Stack Overflow is not the place for debates.  Anyway, the fact that there are "non-evil" applications for `eval` is one reason it still exists.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Some questions which are "locked for historical reasons" have sparked up debates, so why is it illegal to attempt to spark a debate?

Comment: @user1968541: See the FAQ.

Comment: It's still in PHP because not everyone's a noob. Some people can utilize it in an educated fashion; regardless of such memes. And btw, `eval` is the **one** feature that differentiates scripting from compiled languages. If you find it so abhorrent, you're probably using the wrong tool for the job.