# PHP array contents from variable

Tags: php, arrays

In an app that I am building, I would like to create an array using contents that I have in a variable. This is my code:

```
$cont = '"q","w","e","r","t",';
$num = array(eval($cont));
foreach ($num as $v) {
    echo "" . $v . "<br>OK<br><br>";
}
```

It returns nothing. I tried it with the eval, and without What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense

Comment: http://php.net/explode PS: instead of developing custom serialization algorithms it makes sense to check json instead.

Comment: You can't `eval` a random half-formed expression. It has to be valid PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess what you are looking after is `explode()` :

```
$cont = '"q","w","e","r","t","y"';
$num = explode(',',$cont);
foreach ($num as $v) {
    echo "" . $v . "<br>OK<br><br>";
}
```

outputs

```
"q"
OK

"w"
OK
..
```

Comment: If there is comma at last in string, it will print just "OK" in last. For that you can use array_filter() function to filter null values.

Answer (score 0):

`eval` is evil, **[most of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499672/when-if-ever-is-eval-not-evil)**. You can use `preg_match_all` instead:

```
$cont = '"q","w","e","r","t",';
preg_match_all("/\"([^\"]+)\"/", $cont, $matches);
$num = $matches[1];
foreach ($num as $v) {
    echo "$v<br>OK<br><br>";
}
```

Or simply create the array:

```
$num = array("q","w","e","r","t");
foreach ($num as $v) {
    echo "$v<br>OK<br><br>";
}
```

But if all these warnings and alternatives are not enough for you, and you insist on using `eval`, try this:

```
$cont = '"q","w","e","r","t",';
eval("\$num = array($cont);");
foreach ($num as $v) {
    echo "$v<br>OK<br><br>";
}
```