# PHP close tag concatenate confusion

Tags: php

```
eval("\$data = $myvar('https://www.example.com/json/id='". $_GET['name'] ."'))';
```

This got me an error, how to concatenate it properly?

Comment: Please bear in mind that `eval()` is a dangerous function. Avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Eval is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499672/when-if-ever-is-eval-not-evil), but for your specific question above, the quotes were off at the end, and `myvar` is supposed to be a function. See below:

```
eval('$data = myvar("https://www.example.com/json/id='. $_GET['name'] .'");');
```

If you use double quotes like `"$data"` then `$data` will first be evaluated and the result or value will be eval'd instead. This is one of the risks of using `eval()`. If you use double quotes, then escape the `$` signs like so:

```
eval("\$data = myvar('https://www.example.com/json/id=". $_GET['name'] ."');");
```

**Demo:** [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/BdDaA5)

Answer (score 0):

eval("\$data = $myvar('https://www.example.com/json/id=". $_GET['name']."');");

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?