# Converting a function in string format into calculation

Tags: php, laravel, string, calculation

I am programming in php and I have the following variable :

$calculation = '15-12';

Is there a function allowing me to convert the character string into calculation?

Comment: You have `eval`, but [be careful around using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499672/when-if-ever-is-eval-not-evil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can use `eval` expression for such case, but it's not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4096970/884143) (mention by @El_Vanja). It would be better to cast the values to their correct types and do the calculation.

#### `eval` scenario

```
$calculation = '15-12';
$result = eval('return '.$calculation.';');
print $result; // output will be 3
```

#### casted types

```
$calculation = '15-12';

$values = explode('-', $calculation);

$result = intval($values[0]) - intval($values[1]);

print $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `eval()` function could be used here:

```
$calculation = '15-12';
$result = eval('return '.$calculation.';');

echo $result; //outputs '3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval

**Pay attention that this function execute the string like PHP code and if it contains specific mathematical expression, it will fail. In this case you'll need to parse your string and do calculation by yourself or use an external library.**

Answer (score 0):

@aspirinemaga's solution for casting is the approach that I would take.

If it isn't always going to be subtraction (and you want to avoid using eval()) then you could always use `strpos` to figure out if it is adding/subtracting/multiplying and then pass it the expression to a switch statement to get your calc.