# PHP function in XML?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, eval

Is it possible to write a PHP function in a XML

```
<doThis>

doThis(){
bang bang bang!
}

</doThis>
```

and use `simplexml_load_file` to get the object with that function?

```
$foo = simplexml_load_file($xmlAbove);
$foo->doThis();   //bang bang bang!
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. XML is data, not object.

Comment: I don't think so; What if a non-PHP language somehow read the file?

Comment: Not possible. Why don't you use a normal `include` or `require` ?

Comment: Probably you can write the PHP Code to a php file and then include it dynamically, but you should have some security concerns by doing this, since the code will be kind of "injected" to your system without you having checked the code if it is probably violent.

Comment: In [Can PHP include work for only a specified portion of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8508511/367456) there is one answer about [XML Processing Instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8509074/367456)

Comment: You don't want to trust code from input origins. Instead, build an API or similar that allows you to control the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should always consider the security implications of running "code" like this.  If this XML file has remote origins, and you execute the code, then it might do anything.  What about `exec(rm -fR /some/important/path);`?  Or a database call that deletes everything?  There needs to be a very strong trust relationship between the sender and your code, and also strong security protocols to prevent man-in-the-middle and other attacks.

To your question, it is not possible directly.  As commented, XML is data, not code, and is supposed to be portable, meaning your PHP code will be nonsense to another client accepting this XML.

However, you *could* use `eval`.  Maybe like this:

```
eval($foo->doThis);
```

Note: I wouldn't recommend this at all.  It isn't the intended use of XML and it has many problems.  Please, think of some other way.

Answer (score 2):

XML has support for embedding so called [*Processing Instructions* (PI)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi), a valid XML could look like this:

```
<doThis><?php
doThis()
{
   bang bang bang!
}    
?></doThis>
```

which is pretty similar to what you know from the PHP language. However support only means, that you can put processing instructions in there but the processing of those instructions is not of the XML's business.

Also the XML parser you use - [SimpleXML](http://php.net/SimpleXML) - has no dedicated support for processing instructions. You can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/DOMDocument) for that instead. So much from the XML side.

For the PHP side you have got the problem that you somehow define a function while you want to call it instead. Also the PHP code is invalid in other parts (probably because you just put together a quick question). Maybe this is better:

```
<doThis><?php
    function doThis()
    {
        return 'bang bang bang!';
    }
?></doThis>
```

With some little DOM based parser (here called `PiDOMDocument`) this can be turned into a class/object:

```
$doc = new PiDOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$obj = $doc->getObject();
echo $obj->doThis();
```

The output of `echo` in the last line then is:

```
bang bang bang!
```

(quelle surprise). You could internally map this into a SimpleXMLElement to streamline that into your example code above:

```
$foo = simplexml_load_string($xml, 'PiSimpleXMLElement');
echo $foo->doThis();   //bang bang bang!
```

This works like:

```
/**
 * SimpleXMLElement integration of PiDOMDocument
 */
class PiSimpleXMLElement extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public function __call($name, $args) {
        $doc = new PiDOMDocument();
        $doc->loadXML($this->asXML());
        $callback = array($doc->getObject(), $name);
        return call_user_func_array($callback, $args);
    }
}
```

As PHP processor you can take `eval` or `include` ([which basically is both the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1184628/367456)). PHP is executed directly so if your code has fatal parse errors, the overall script has fatal errors, if you do not like this PHP default behavior, you can parse the string before eval'ing it for such errors, see as well [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token_get_all) and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7874314/367456) or [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3268443/367456).

I opted for an unvalidated `eval` in my [online demo](http://eval.in/9908) / [example code as gist](https://gist.github.com/hakre/4959346).